# Running EXE files in linux apache like a CGI

Tags: linux, apache, cgi, executable

I have an old system which connects to my custom hardware that I will be delivering simple HTML out of.

If I wanted to waste electricity, I'd have two computers constantly running and then I can test my pages on the fly.

Instead, I want to do all my work on one computer my linux system.

Currently I can serve CGI pages through Apache in Linux and those are compiled C programs.

But because the target computer has Quick Basic and I compile EXE files through that language, I can do the same on my linux computer through DOSBOX.

The nice news is I can execute my Quick Basic program on a unix commandline via the linux WineConsole command and the output prints correctly despite the warning messages printed to stderr.

The sad news is I can't find a way to load my EXE as if it was part of a URL in a browser and have the same contents shown in the browser itself as what I saw on the commandline.

My only guess is to find a specialized apache module that can allow me to associate extensions with programs but I don't know of such a module.

Is there another way one can run an EXE file in linux apache and have the standard output contents dumped to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dosemu instead of dosbox?

If dosemu is able to output to stdout, you can wrap it inside a shell script that will be your CGI

Comment: I tried it but sadly it won't output to stdout. Also, it won't allow me to directly access a program of my choice with a clean exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using DOS specific routines in your basic code, you might be better of compiling it as a linux executable using a basic compiler for linux.

You might want to look into this. I know there is a compiler called [FreeBasic](https://www.freebasic.net) which should be able to compile QuickBasic code to a linux executable.